# Why is M-x remapped in ansi-term char mode?

Tags: ansi-term

I understand that you can use `M-x` in ansi-term's *char mode* by doing `C-x M-x`, but why can't it just be used normally? Is there some historical reason? I can use other meta commands (like `M-f` or `M-b`), why does `M-x` need the `C-x` prefix key?
(Also, I understand that `M-x` works normally in *line mode*.)

Comment: Think about the case where you are running emacs inside ansi-term, how do you send `M-x` to the inner vs outer Emacs?

Comment: You could swap in any key sequence and ask the same question. For instance: How would you send `C-x` to the inner vs the outer Emacs? Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Yes, you can ask the question for any key, though the answer is a bit different for `C-x` in particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't the special case that you think it is.

In general, Meta key sequences can be used in terminals (and the inferior process might have its own use for `M-x`), so term char mode sends these keys to the terminal.

Just like `M-x` itself, `M-f` and `M-b` are bound to `term-send-raw-meta` in term char mode.  The inferior process running in the terminal is simply reacting to them in much the same way that you're used to them behaving in Emacs.

Note that if those keys were *actually* invoking `forward-word` and `backward-word` then the inferior process running in the terminal *wouldn't know that you'd done anything* (although since Emacs 26.1, the user options `term-char-mode-point-at-process-mark` and `term-char-mode-buffer-read-only` also prevent such things from creating confusion by default).

Comment: "The terminal line discipline (or the inferior process itself) is simply reacting to them in much the same way that you're used to them behaving in Emacs." Ah, those work because those keybindings are part of the terminal, just like you could open up any terminal (outside of Emacs) (or most any) and they'd work.

Comment: It's really much more likely to be the process running in the terminal (e.g. a shell) than the terminal itself.  Any program with more than the most *trivial* of user-input requirements will set the terminal to 'raw' mode (as opposed to the 'cooked' or 'canonical' mode which provides that extremely basic line-editing support), at which point any line editing is being dealt with purely by the inferior process.  There's still a lot of consistency between programs, though, as so many of them use `readline` to handle the user input, or endeavour to be compatible with that.